# How to use VeryCrypt to encrypt Ubuntu system on LVM using command line?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, truecrypt, disk-encryption, veracrypt

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 server installed on **LVM** disk, and I need to encrypt that disk using any encrypting tool (I prefer **VeraCrypt**), and let the users enter the passwor pre-booting to encrypt the disk.

I found that option (System Partition Encryption) on the GUI version of VeraCrypt, but I need to do that from the Ubuntu **command line**. Could some one help me to do that?

Please note that I need to keep the data, so I want to encrypt the disk **without losing any data**.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Supported%20Systems%20for%20System%20Encryption) only Windows operating systems are available for system encryption.  For Ubuntu 16.04, there are other options for system disk encryption, I do not know how compatible they are with Veracrypt.

Comment: Could you mention what are the options for Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: For full disk encryption for Ubuntu, it is built in to the installation process.  I have not looked into it heavily, but [from what I have seen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/366749/enable-disk-encryption-after-installation) it is not easy to do after installation without losing data, which was one of your conditions.

Comment: I already found that, but I have a lot of data, therefore any method leads to data losing doesn't help.